# How do I know which SObject the PageName from LightningUsageByPageMetrics refers to?

Tags: lightning, api, standard-objects

I'm trying to map the PageName property from the `LightningUsageByPageMetric` object back to Standard Objects. E.g. a `PageName` = "Contact Record" is presumably associated to the `Contact` SObject. But there are tons of unique `PageName`s that aren't as clear which SObject they are associated to. Is there a way to get a deterministic map from PageName : SObject ?

`LightningUsageByPageMetrics` : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_lightningusagebypagemetrics.htm